Import CSV to Oracle Script DB
I managed to export data from a table in an Oracle database in .csv format using SQL Plus.
I have this file locally.
Now I need to import this same .csv file into another table in another Oracle database.
The version of Oracle here at work is 11.2 and does not have the SQL Loader utility.
What can I use to perform this import?
I thought about creating a script that has a truncate and a code to take line by line from the CSV file and insert it into the database. How do I do this?
Thank you


The version of Oracle here ... does not have the SQL Loader utility.

That's a real shame because that's precisely the tool you need to do this job properly.
Another alternative might be to use your favourite scripting language to convert the csv into SQL insert statements that you could execute through sqlplus.  YMMV.

The version of Oracle here at work is 11.2 ...

That version went out of support some four years ago now!
You really, really need to think about upgrading.

How can I execute this script that imports data into a table in an Oracle database? This will be included in a routine in a Linux environment, a script made in Windows would not work. Wouldn't a command only through SQL Plus solve the problem?

Have you had a look at SQLcl? You can load and unload using this tool: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sqlcl-unload-and-load-table-data

@JoyceFerreira Use awk or perl (or whatever) to reformat the csv into Insert statements, then feed them into sqlplus the same as you would any other SQL script.
sqlplus connection < script
